# How can I clear git status?

Tags: git

```
Ericks-MacBook-Air:~ erickmartinez$ git status
On branch master

No commits yet

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

    .Trash/
    .atom/
    .bash_history
    .bash_sessions/
    .config/
    .cups/
    .gitconfig
    .kodi/
    .ssh/
    .viminfo
    67 Steps/
    Applications/
    Desktop/
    Documents/
    Downloads/
    Google Drive/
    Library/
    Movies/
    Music/
    Pictures/
    Public/
    iCloud Drive (Archive)/

nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
```

Comment: What do you want to achieve here?

Comment: If you are trying to ignore certain files or directories, you can use a gitignore file.  Those files won't be listed in git status.  See https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore

Comment: When it did this, I couldn't "git add ." the real changes I wanted to push on my HTML and CSS files. That's why I wanted to clear everything from "git status"

Answer (score 1):

If you want to avoid having to put everything in a .gitignore file, you can also use `git status -uno` to avoid showing any untracked files. If you want to have that be the default behaviour, you can set the `status.showUntrackedFiles` config option to "no", which has the same effect:

```
git config status.showUntrackedFiles no
```

That will set the option just for the current repository; if you want to set it globally, pass the `--global` flag.

Answer (score 0):

Make a .gitignore file and put all file that you do not want to add or commit in it , it will ignore all file that you have put in it.

```
.Trash/
.atom/
.bash_history
.bash_sessions/
.config/
.cups/
.gitconfig
.kodi/
.ssh/
.viminfo
```

for more information click here

https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore

Comment: Thank you very much! Also do you know if there is a way to clear the git status?